# How to catch UI button clicks in script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script and I need somehow catch moment when user click my button BUT only in script.
For example, it must be equal like   "if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))" but instead GetKeyDown my UI button.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to your button.

```
button.onClick.AddListener(DoSomething);

void DoSomething()
{
     // do something
}
```

If you need to assign parameters on your method you can use

```
button.onClick.AddListener(delegate { DoSomething("abc");});

void DoSomething(string something)
{
     // do something
}
```

After your button is pressed the code inside the DoSomething method will be triggerd.